# Extract different format date from a string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have several strings, and have identified some formats of date on them, and would like to recognize date on each string

```
an_2011_02_12_azar.mp3 ->this is yyyy_mm_dd
20121112_Marcel.mp3    ->this is yyyymmdd
cdani_270607.mp3       ->this is ddmmyy
lica_07_03_15.mp3      ->this is dd_mm_yy
```

to do so I have:

```
foo = """
an_2011_02_12_azar.mp3
20121112_Marcel.mp3   
cdani_270607.mp3     
lica_07_03_15.mp3  
"""
try:
    lines = foo.split('\n')
except AttributeError:
    lines = x
for line in lines:
     print(line)
     #deals with 2011_02_12 format
     match = re.search(r'\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}', line)
     date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y_%m_%d').date()
     print(date)
```

How to apply several regular expressions so it can recognize dates?

Comment: Loop over the patterns?

Comment: When looping and string does not have `%Y_%m_%d` I geterror  `date = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(), '%Y_%m_%d').date()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' `

Comment: So either check for `None` or handle the error and move on, and `break`/`return` when one parses successfully.

Comment: Is there a way to apply `OR`  on regular expression?

Comment: so `match = re.search(r'\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}', line) | re.search(r'\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}', line) ...` would work?

Comment: No, the pipe goes *in the pattern*. Try reading the Python `re` docs, or just use a loop outside of regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the underscores:

```
datestr = line.replace('_', '')
```

then there would be only two date formats to deal with: `yyyymmdd` or `ddmmyy`.
Furthermore, every date string would consist of 6 to 8 digits which you could
find using the regex pattern `r'\d{8}|\d{6}'`:

```
datestr = re.search(r'\d{8}|\d{6}', datestr).group()
```

The `datestr` could then be parsed with either

```
date = DT.datetime.strptime(datestr, '%d%m%y')
```

or

```
date = DT.datetime.strptime(datestr, '%Y%m%d')
```

The pattern `r'\d{8}|\d{6}'` would also capture some possibly non-date-like strings, such digits which represent invalid dates. We could deal with those cases by using `try..except` to catch `ValueErrors`.

---

```
import re
import datetime as DT

foo = """\
an_2011_02_12_azar.mp3
20121112_Marcel.mp3   
cdani_270607.mp3     
lica_07_03_15.mp3  
an_2011_13_12_azar.mp3
"""

for line in foo.splitlines():
    datestr = line.replace('_', '')
    datestr = re.search(r'\d{8}|\d{6}', datestr).group()
    try:
        # %y matches 2-digit years
        date = DT.datetime.strptime(datestr, '%d%m%y')
    except ValueError:
        try:
            # %Y matches 4-digit years
            date = DT.datetime.strptime(datestr, '%Y%m%d')
        except ValueError:
            # handle the error case
            date = None
    print('{:23} --> {}'.format(line, date))
```

yields

```
an_2011_02_12_azar.mp3  --> 2011-02-12 00:00:00
20121112_Marcel.mp3     --> 2012-11-12 00:00:00
cdani_270607.mp3        --> 2007-06-27 00:00:00
lica_07_03_15.mp3       --> 2015-03-07 00:00:00
an_2011_13_12_azar.mp3  --> None
```